# On single.php, fetch 2 posts created after and 2 posts created before in relation to the actual post (using menu_order)

Tags: loop, single

Looking for a way to on single.php fetch and show the actual post, and then by looking on the menu_order value of that specific post (lets say the post have menu_order value 3 in this case) go and fetch the 2 posts before that one i.e. the posts with menu_order value 1 and 2. Also fetch 2 posts after, i.e. the posts with the value 4 and 5. And how you'd check to see if there even are as many as +/- 2 posts in relation the the current post.

Anyone have an idea how to sort that out?